# Transportation fee + Lunch money =?

Tags: phrase-requests

> My son goes out for the day every weekend, so I have to give him transportation fee and lunch money every time he does so.

I'd like to know if the above sentence sounds natural to native speakers. My concerns are:

1. Is there any way to make the expression "transportation fee and lunch money" shorter? I'm wondering if it can be described as "xx for transportation and lunch".
2. Is it awkward if I omit "he does so" and put the period after "time"?

Comment: In business accounting in the UK this type of expenditure is sometimes collectively categorised as _travel and subsistence_ (abbreviated _T&S_), but it would sound unnatural in a personal context to say “I give my son T&S”.

Answer (score 7):

What about *pocket money* to cover both lunch and transportation?

Pocket money is defined as: money for day-to-day spending, incidental expenses, etc.

---

So you could revise your sentence to something like:

Each time my son goes out for the day, I have to give him pocket money.

Answer (score 5):

"transportation fee" sounds very artificial "bus/train fare" would be more normal

Answer (score 4):

I have to give him money for travel and lunch.

Answer (score 3):

My son takes leave of home on the weekend, and I give him a per diem.

Comment: +1 That's the phrase I've heard the most. At work though. It's fun to use it at home too.

Comment: In AmE, at least on the Northeast US, this is sentence is awkward and `per diem` is a jargon term typically *only* used by a lawyer etc. in a professional context.

Comment: I know "per diem" from labour law context...

Answer (score 1):

The subject sentence,

> My son goes out for the day every weekend, so I have to give him transportation fee and lunch money every time he does so.

does indeed sound odd.  (That is not to say it could not or would not be written by a native speaker; many native speakers are quite accomplished at writing oddly.)

The first odd item is "out for the day every weekend".  One might say "out for the day each Saturday" (or Sunday) but there's a clash between "for the day" (one day) and "the weekend" (two).  "A day" might work.

An article (*a* or *the*) is needed before "transportation fee".  As bio-text.com notes in [ESL2](http://bio-text.com/ESL2.html), "Singular countable nouns require an article. Plural countable nouns and all non-countable nouns do not require an article."

Thus, you could write "... give him the transportation fee and his lunch money...".  Of course, to shorten it all, instead write "... give him transportation and lunch money...", letting *transportation* and *lunch* be adjectives modifying *money*.  Or, more briefly and perhaps idiomatically, "... give him travel and lunch money...".

Finally, in place of "every time he does so", write "each time", giving:

> My son goes out for a day each weekend, and I must give him travel and lunch money each time.

Comment: I think she means that her son leaves home for the entire day on both Saturday and Sunday, presumably returning at night. Your revision "...out for a day each weekend..." is not the same thing.

Comment: @JLG: That's a matter of interpretation, but it's irrelevant anyway - jwpat correctly nails OP's substantive question with *"travel and lunch money"*.

Answer (score 0):

How about, "My son goes out all day on weekends, so I have to give him bus fare and lunch money."

But I am still not comfortable with the first half of the sentence.  Can you specify where he goes?  That might make it less awkward:

"My son goes to the city most weekend days, so I have to give him bus fare and lunch money."

Answer (score 0):

> My son goes out for the day every weekend, so I have to give him
>   transportation fee and lunch money every time he does so.
>
> I'd like to know if the above sentence sounds natural to native
>   speakers. My concerns are:
>
> Is there any way to make the expression "transportation fee and lunch
>   money" shorter? I'm wondering if it can be described as "xx for
>   transportation and lunch".
>
> Is it awkward if I omit "he does so" and put the period after "time"?

Not just if you omit “he does so”; the entire sentence does not sound natural.

The word *transportation* (instead of *transport*). There's nothing wrong with the word *transport*, as it is. It is the natural and normal way for English (and other British) people to use the word. Also, putting the word *money* after the word *lunch* is not natural. It's more natural to say *money* for *lunch*.

The first part of your sentence, “My son goes out for the day every weekend”, is unclear. There is more than one day in weekends. Do you mean that he goes out for one day or both days, every weekend? If it’s one day, you can say “My son goes out for one day every weekend.” If it’s both days, you can say “My son goes out for the day, every Saturday and Sunday.’

Therefore, your sentence can be: “My son goes out for one day every weekend.” Or, “My son goes out for the day, every Saturday and Sunday, so I have to give him money for transport and lunch, every time."

This would be the more natural and common way to say it, at least to me as a speaker of British English.

Answer (score 0):

"Expenses coverage", I would say.